# Find the $x$ values for which my function has a horizontal tangent.

Tags: derivatives, polynomials

I want to find the $x$ values for which the following function has a horizontal tangent line:

$$\sqrt{x^2-2x+2}+\sqrt{x^2-6x+12}$$

My attempt so far has been to compute the derivative, which I found to be $$\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{x^2-2x+2}}+\frac{x-3}{\sqrt{x^2-6x+12}}$$However, I wasn't able to find the $x$ values for which this expression is $0$.

Comment: Have you computed the derivative?

Comment: yes, (x-1)/√(x^2-2x+2)+(x-3)/√(x^2-6x+13)

Comment: Have you tried setting it equal to zero and solving?

Comment: But to have that equal to zero and try to get the value of x is not gong anywhere with me, something is wrong or it's beyond my ability, any help please, hint?

Comment: The obvious hint would be: "Do what Don Thousand said".

Comment: I did that, guys, I tried for two days of using all I can but it's going nowhere

Comment: @ibrahimMohamed I have rewritten your question in a fashion that would be better received on this site. I'd recommend reading through our help center, and in particular, [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) on how to ask a good question.

Comment: thank you, Don you put it in a perfect way. Appreciate it ^^

Comment: @SaucyO'Path I'm new here, first question for a college student who wants to do better in life and study, what Don did is something called fact finding, he asked real questions, that helped me clarify what I want, what you did is just assuming I' lazy, I can give you 5 pages of me trying to solve it, Thanks anyway.

Comment: @ibrahimMohamed I don't think that's very nice. Users like Saucy spend many hours making sure that the quality of this site is high. I understand that this is confusing, but without users like Saucy, this website would be cluttered with junk.

Comment: I'm sorry, no disrespect intended.

Comment: As per the question, I'd find the answer via numerical approximation (more precisely, the Newton-Raphson method) to be $\sqrt3$, but I'm struggling with finding a proper analytical approach to getting that answer...

Comment: thank you, i really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Set your expression of $f'(x)$ equal to $0$  to express that you have an extremum.

Write this condition under the form:

$$\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{x^2-2x+2}}=-\frac{x-3}{\sqrt{x^2-6x+12}}\tag{1}$$

Square the two sides of (1) giving

$$\frac{N_1(x)}{D_1(x)}=\frac{N_2(x)}{D_2(x)}$$

giving you a polynomial equation:

$$N_1(x)D_2(x)-N_2(x)D_1(x)=0$$

otherwise said:

$$(x-1)^2(x^2-6x+12)-(x-3)^2(x^2-2x+2)=0$$

$$(x-1)^2((x-3)^2+3)-(x-3)^2((x-1)^2+1)=0\tag{2}$$

Let us expand (2) under the form:

$$(x-1)^2 . (x-3)^2+(x-1)^2 . 3 \ - \ (x-3)^2(x-1)^2-(x-3)^2 . 1=0$$

By cancellation of terms $(x-1)^2 . (x-3)^2$:

$$3(x-1)^2-(x-3)^2=0$$

a quadratic equation with two real roots.

Take care: check the solutions against the initial equation (1); indeed a spurious solution has been introduced by the squaring step.

Comment: thank you, but I need the values of x as I need the points of all tangent lines. Do you know how to get the values?

Comment: I just added the "almost final" computation.

Comment: I've reached that (−1)2((−3)2+3)−(−3)2((−1)2+1)=0  step before in one of my attempts but  I couldn't think of any number I can replace with x and it will be working, that's why I'm stuck and not sure what to do!

Comment: Have you seen that the terms $(x-1)^2(x-3)^2$ $-(x-1)^2(x-3)^2$ are cancelling ?

Comment: I'm really sorry I don't know how and the last step of your answer I can't follow what happened ^^"

Comment: Is it clearer now with this intermediate step ? If not, you can plainly expand (2) and obtain as well the quadratic equation.

Comment: Thanks a lot I see if now 